# Geometry node: Switching points on the furthest X point

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm still struggling my way through making a city block using geometry nodes. I'm almost finished getting it to how I want to, but I want to be able to have the ends of my block use a different set of instances to the middle. So the instances on the furthest X and -X edges are different to those along the Y and -Y edges

Here is the node set up for part of my block: [image]

This is the section of nodes I have set up to try and be able to switch the ends of the blocks to choose different parts of my collection.

[image]

As you can see below if I use the integer node switching between zero and one will switch successfully between different ID's from the collection.
[image]

[[image]

[image][image][image]

What I'd like to know is how can I isolate the X and -X edges and change ONLY the ends of the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you know what x size you have and how many vertices there are, you can do easy mathematical calculations to get what you want:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome, glad i could help